# Symfony2 date validation fails

Tags: date, symfony, validation

I've a form type which looks like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('birthdate', 'date'));
}
```

**My validator:**

```
Foo\BarBundle\Model\User\Profile:
    properties:
        birthdate:
            - NotNull:
                message : label.null
            - Date:
                message: user.profile.birthdate.invalid
```

**My request with request body data:**

PUT foo.dev/user/profile

```
{ 
    "user_profile" : { 
        "sex" : 0,
        "birthdate" : {
            "year"  : 1983,
            "month" : 6,
            "day"   : 23
        },
        "height" : 180,
        "weight" : 78,
        "pal"    : 1.2
    }
}
```

This gives me a 400:

```
{
    "code":400,
    "message":"Validation Failed",
    "errors":{
    "children":{
        "birthdate":{
            "errors":[
                "This value is not valid."
            ],
            "children":{
                "year":[],
                "month":[],
                "day":[]
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Same happens, If I use this:

PUT foo.dev/user/profile

```
{ 
    "user_profile" : { 
        "sex" : 0,
        "birthdate" : "2014-01-01",
        "height" : 180,
        "weight" : 78,
        "pal"    : 1.2
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Pls help :'(

**Update:**

If I use `widget` => `single_text`, when adding the form field, I can successfully request this endpoint with `birthdate` : `1974-05-06`, but I want to be able, to send more then only 1 format:

- Datetime Object
- Timestamp
- YYYY-MM-DD
- Array

Comment: I suggest you to use [data transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html). But I think that accepting multiple formats will require lot of work to recognize then parse each format. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**
If I use widget => text, I can send the three sub form fields as expected. But I cant send those values as a string.

Nevertheless....I'll close this.