# How to send a date as JSON string to symfony2?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, date, symfony

I try to send data from a HTML form to a REST API which is created with the Symfony 2 PHP framework. The form data is processed with javascript (AngularJS) and send as JSON string to the API. Sending the data as HTTP PUT request works well. The problem appears if I try to validate the data.

To validate the data I created a form class and use the form validation mechanism of symfony2. Here the problem appears. The validation mechanism does not recognize my date format ... I tried it with the following format :

{'year':'2014','month':'05','day':'15'}

and

2014-05-15

In both cases the validation throws the error "birthday:\n ERROR: This value is not valid.\n"

I would be very pleased if someone could give me a hint to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532510/symfony2-date-validation-fails?rq=1) but without a satisfying answer.

Comment: Could you provide the validation function code you have?

Comment: Try to create `dataTransformer` and create `\DateTime` object. But I have looked at `DateValidator` and passing string should work.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers ! I'll try the dataTransformer and post my results here then.